# No remote stream using kurento docker image with kurento hello world example on host

Tags: fiware, kurento

I installed a KMS container on my server and I downloaded kurento hello world java application on my server but when I go to my java web application using my server IP adress I have to remote stream and and the following error (in firefox):

```
ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details
```

in the about:webrtc It tells me that there is no STUN and no TURN server specified (and a lot of following output not very clear to me) The problem is that I specified a STUN server on the WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
kurento:
image: fiware/stream-oriented-kurento:latest
volumes:
    - ./kurento.conf.json:/etc/kurento/kurento.conf.json:ro
    - ./defaultCertificate.pem:/etc/kurento/defaultCertificate.pem:ro
    - ./WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini:/etc/kurento/modules/kurento/WebRtcEndpoint$
ports:
    - "8888:8888"
    - "8433:8433"
```

here is my kurento.conf.json file:

```
{
"mediaServer" : {
"resources": {
//  //Resources usage limit for raising an exception when an object creatio$
//  "exceptionLimit": "0.8",
//  // Resources usage limit for restarting the server when no objects are $
//  "killLimit": "0.7",
    // Garbage collector period in seconds
    "garbageCollectorPeriod": 240
},

    "net" : {
  "websocket": {
    "port": 8888,
    "secure": {
      "port": 8433,
      "certificate": "defaultCertificate.pem",
      "password": ""
    },
    //"registrar": {
    //  "address": "ws://localhost:9090",
    //  "localAddress": "localhost"
    //},
    "path": "kurento",
    "threads": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini

```
; Only IP address are supported, not domain names for addresses
; You have to find a valid stun server. You can check if it works
; usin this tool:
;   http://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ 
stunServerAddress=62.71.2.168
stunServerPort=3478

; turnURL gives the necessary info to configure TURN for WebRTC.
;    'address' must be an IP (not a domain).
;    'transport' is optional (UDP by default).
; turnURL=user:password@address:port(?transport=[udp|tcp|tls])

;pemCertificate is deprecated. Please use pemCertificateRSA instead
;pemCertificate=<path>
;pemCertificateRSA=<path>
;pemCertificateECDSA=<path>
```

and the certificate has been generated with :

```
certtool --generate-privkey --outfile defaultCertificate.pem
echo 'organization = your organization name' > certtool.tmpl
certtool --generate-self-signed --load-privkey defaultCertificate.pem \
--template certtool.tmpl >> defaultCertificate.pem

sudo chown kurento defaultCertificate.pem
```

and I went on my https://localhost:8433/kurento to validate the certificate

When I start the kurento container with docker-compose up I can see on the logs that my conf. file has been loaded:

```
kurento_1           |             "websocket":
kurento_1           |             {
kurento_1           |                 "port": "8888",
kurento_1           |                 "secure":
kurento_1           |                 {
kurento_1           |                     "port": "8433",
kurento_1           |                     "certificate": 
"defaultCertificate.pem",
kurento_1           |                     "password": ""
kurento_1           |                 },
kurento_1           |                 "path": "kurento",
kurento_1           |                 "threads": "10"
kurento_1           |             }
```

.....

```
kurento_1           |             "WebRtcEndpoint":
kurento_1           |             {
kurento_1           |                 "stunServerAddress": "62.71.2.168",
kurento_1           |                 "stunServerPort": "3478",
kurento_1           |                 "configPath": 
"\/etc\/kurento\/modules\/kurento"
kurento_1           |             },
```

and I start the hello world example with :

```
sudo mvn compile exec:java -Dkms.url=wss://localhost:8433/kurento
```

at this point everything seems to work OK, no error output.

When I try to access my web application from a client with https://:8443 the web page is loaded correctly and can start the stream. But I have no remote stream and have the error I printed at the beginning.

**UPDATE 1**

I changed the version of the kurento image in docker-compose.yml from

```
image: fiware/stream-oriented-kurento:latest
```

to:

```
image: fiware/stream-oriented-kurento:6.6.0
```

And now it is working sometimes. I have the same error (*ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details*) but if I reload the page multiple time, it end up working after some reload. Any suggestion about what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2**

I realized that when the web application start working (after multiple reload), the next time I access the web applicaiton, it will always work, until I restart the KMS. Then I have to reaload the page multiple time again to have the remote stream.

Now that I realized that, I tried again with *image: fiware/stream-oriented-kurento:latest* and it has the exact same behavior. I have to reload multiple time the page to make it work. I have no clue why is that, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Looking into your problem I feel the ICE candidates have not been created properly on both sides.

Have you configured the STUN / TURN in the webApplication (JS)? 
*If you haven't modify the example I believe they are not configured by default*

Check into the options.configuration. Example:

```
var options  = {
        ........ some options here .... 
        configuration: { 
               iceServers:[{ 
                       "url": "turn:xxx.xxx.xxx:port", 
                       "username": "xxxxxx", 
                       "credential": "xxxxxx" 
              }] 
        } 
webRtcPeer = new kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendrecv(options,<callback-here>);
```

Can you provide logs for both the Firefox ICE candidates generation and KMS ICE generation?

In addition is KMS up and running in the same machine as the tutorial?

- More information about **kurento_utils** used in the hello-world: http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/kurento_utils_js.html#using-data-channels
- General example of WebRTC configuration the STUN on the Web client side:
  https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#simple-peer-to-peer-example